# Modifying value in Link List - Returns list edited but it is missing a node. (C)

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes

My modify function is working, but for some reason when i print it out there is a node missing from the list. The node i want to edit is edited though. I figure the problem is i am assigning mod->next to current -> next somehow when i should be assigning it current. I can't solve it. Been trying different combinations for a while now.  Thanks for the help

```
void modify(int modID,double modsal){
    type *current;
    type *mod;
    current = head;

    if (current != NULL)
    {
        // if first node 
        if (current->ID == modID){
            current->sal = modsal;
            head =  current;
            printf("\nPerson with ID %d has a new pay\n",modID);
            return;
        }

        mod = current;

        // Otherwise, loop for value
        while (current->next != NULL){
            if (current->ID == modID){
                current->sal = modsal;
                printf("\nPerson with ID %d has a new pay\n",modID);
                head = mod;
                return;
            }
            current = current -> next;
            mod -> next = current;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are doing more than modifying one node in the list, you are modifying the list itself. Is that what you want? What is the purpose of the variable `mod`? It seems that if you remove all the lines using `mod` then you will be fine.

Comment: I want to locate a node in the list and edit the data of that node. (New to all of this) but when i did not have the mod it was not editing the list.

Comment: why are you using `head =  current;` `mod = current;` `head = mod;`mod -> next = current;`

the way you said that you just have to modify a specific node, you will never need to change the node to which head is pointing, then why change it?

Comment: @clcto Thanks! Didn't need the mod. Removed it and changed the while loop check and its working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mod` is only assigned to once:

```
mod = current;
```

And at this point, `current` is the `head`, so `mod` is just another pointer to the head. In the loop you say:

```
mod->next = current;
```

And since `mod` is `head` you remove all the nodes between the `head` and `current`. So if the node you are trying to modify is at the end of the list, you will end up with just those 2 nodes in the list.

Remove `mod` it isn't needed:

```
type *current;
current = head;

if (current != NULL)
{
    // if first node 
    if (current->ID == modID){
        current->sal = modsal;
        printf("\nPerson with ID %d has a new pay\n",modID);
        return;
    }

    // Otherwise, loop for value
    while (current->next != NULL){
        if (current->ID == modID){
            current->sal = modsal;
            printf("\nPerson with ID %d has a new pay\n",modID);
            return;
        }
        current = current -> next;
    }
}
```

Also, you don't want to reassign `head` since that will change the list. It happened to work since you were reassigning it with itself, so it didn't change.

**Edit noticed another bug**

Your `while` loop is checking the next value is not null, so you never check the last value in the list. You can collapse your code a little and remove this issue:

```
type *current;
current = head;

while(current != NULL)
{
    if (current->ID == modID){
        current->sal = modsal;
        printf("\nPerson with ID %d has a new pay\n",modID);
        return;
    }
    current = current -> next;
}
```

This is the common way to loop through a linked list.

```
node* current = head;
while( current != NULL )
{
    // do stuff with current
    current = current->next;
}
```

Comment: "so you never check the last value in the list" thanks! this was my problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change the salary of the node whose modID is received by the function, then this code is enough

```
void modify(int modID,double modsal){
    type *current;
    type *mod;
    current = head;

    if (current != NULL)
    {
        // if first node 
        if (current->ID == modID){
            current->sal = modsal;
            //head =  current; (not needed)
            printf("\nPerson with ID %d has a new pay\n",modID);
            return;
    }
    //mod = current; (not needed)   
    // Otherwise, loop for value
    while (current != NULL){
        if (current->ID == modID){
            current->sal = modsal;
            printf("\nPerson with ID %d has a new pay\n",modID);
            //head = mod; (not needed)
            return;
        }
        current = current -> next;
        //mod -> next = current; (not needed)
    }
}
```

}